TLS connection Error from exim4
My mail server, which is operated with myVesta, has a problem when I want to send mails. (Receiving works)
Unfortunately I only get the error from Thunderbird
mailnews.send: Sending failed; The message could not be sent because the connection to Outgoing server (SMTP) XXXXX.XXXXXX.de timed out. Try again., exitCode=2153066800, originalMsgURI=

In the exim4 mainlog there is also only the error
2024-08-17 08:50:31 TLS error on connection from Xxxxxxx.xxx.t-ipconnect.de [X.X.X.X.X] (gnutls_handshake): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.

System: Debian 12 (Up To Date)
MyVesta: Latest version
Thunderbird Setting for the Server
Description:    domain.tld Mail
Server Name:    mail04.domain.tld
Port:   465
User Name:  mail@domain.tld
Authentication method:  Normal password
Connection Security:    SSL/TLS


    root@mail04:/var/log# netstat -tulpen
Aktive Internetverbindungen (Nur Server)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       Benutzer   Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          16801      609/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          16786      609/dovecot
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:783           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          16926      615/perl
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          20052      1184/exim4
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          20051      1184/exim4
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          16799      609/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          20050      1184/exim4
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          16784      609/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2525            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          20053      1184/exim4
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2253            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          19070      797/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8083            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          13728      794/nginx: master p
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      102        13735      785/mariadbd
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          16802      609/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          16787      609/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          16800      609/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          16785      609/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 ::1:783                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          16925      615/perl
tcp6       0      0 :::2253                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          19072      797/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      102        13736      785/mariadbd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           0          19582      539/dhclient

Exim4 Config
######################################################################
#                                                                    #
#          Exim configuration file for Vesta Control Panel           #
#                                                                    #
######################################################################

SPAMASSASSIN = yes
SPAM_SCORE = 50
CLAMD =  yes

disable_ipv6=true
add_environment=<; PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
keep_environment=
smtputf8_advertise_hosts =

#local_interfaces =  0.0.0.0
#smtp_active_hostname = ${lookup{$interface_address}lsearch{/etc/exim4/virtual/helo_data}{$value}}
#smtp_banner = "$smtp_active_hostname ESMTP $tod_full"

domainlist local_domains = dsearch;/etc/exim4/domains/
domainlist relay_to_domains = dsearch;/etc/exim4/domains/
hostlist relay_from_hosts = 127.0.0.1
hostlist whitelist = net-iplsearch;/etc/exim4/white-blocks.conf
hostlist spammers = net-iplsearch;/etc/exim4/spam-blocks.conf
no_local_from_check
untrusted_set_sender = *
acl_smtp_connect = acl_check_spammers
acl_smtp_mail = acl_check_mail
acl_smtp_rcpt = acl_check_rcpt
acl_smtp_data = acl_check_data
acl_smtp_mime = acl_check_mime

LIMIT_PER_EMAIL_ACCOUNT_MAX_RECIPIENTS = 15
LIMIT_PER_HOSTING_ACCOUNT_MAX_RECIPIENTS = 5
LIMIT_PER_EMAIL_ACCOUNT_MAX_SENT_EMAILS_PER_HOUR = 40
LIMIT_PER_HOSTING_ACCOUNT_MAX_SENT_EMAILS_PER_HOUR = 40

recipients_max = 150
recipients_max_reject = true

# log_selector = +smtp_connection
smtp_accept_max = 50
smtp_accept_max_per_host = 4

.ifdef SPAMASSASSIN
spamd_address = 127.0.0.1 783
.endif

.ifdef CLAMD
av_scanner = clamd: /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl
.endif

tls_advertise_hosts = *
tls_certificate = /usr/local/vesta/ssl/certificate.crt
tls_privatekey = /usr/local/vesta/ssl/certificate.key

daemon_smtp_ports = 25 : 465 : 587 : 2525
tls_on_connect_ports = 465
never_users = root
host_lookup = *
rfc1413_hosts = *
rfc1413_query_timeout = 0s
ignore_bounce_errors_after = 2d
timeout_frozen_after = 7d

DKIM_DOMAIN = ${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}
DKIM_FILE = /etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/dkim.pem
DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY = ${if exists{DKIM_FILE}{DKIM_FILE}{0}}



######################################################################
#                       ACL CONFIGURATION                            #
#         Specifies access control lists for incoming SMTP mail      #
######################################################################

acl_not_smtp = acl_not_smtp

begin acl

acl_not_smtp:
  deny message = Too many recipients, limit is $acl_c_max_recipients recipients
  set acl_c_max_recipients=${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/exim4/limit_per_hosting_account_max_recipients}{$value}{LIMIT_PER_HOSTING_ACCOUNT_MAX_RECIPIENTS}}
  condition = ${if >{$rcpt_count}{$acl_c_max_recipients}}

  deny message = Hosting account is sending too much emails [limitlog]: deny / account / $authenticated_id / $sender_rate / $sender_rate_period [limit=$acl_c_limit_per_hour]
  set acl_c_limit_per_hour=${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/exim4/limit_per_hosting_account_max_sent_emails_per_hour}{$value}{LIMIT_PER_HOSTING_ACCOUNT_MAX_SENT_EMAILS_PER_HOUR}}
  ratelimit = $acl_c_limit_per_hour / 1h / $authenticated_id

  warn ratelimit = 0 / 1h / strict / $authenticated_id
  set acl_c_limit_per_hour=${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/exim4/limit_per_hosting_account_max_sent_emails_per_hour}{$value}{LIMIT_PER_HOSTING_ACCOUNT_MAX_SENT_EMAILS_PER_HOUR}}
  log_message = Sender rate [limitlog]: log / account / $authenticated_id / $sender_rate / $sender_rate_period [limit=$acl_c_limit_per_hour]

  warn    set acl_m3    = yes

  accept

acl_check_spammers:
  accept  hosts         = +whitelist

  drop    message       = Your host in blacklist on this server.
          log_message   = Host in blacklist
          hosts         = +spammers

  accept


acl_check_mail:
  deny    condition     = ${if eq{$sender_helo_name}{}}
          message       = HELO required before MAIL

  drop    !authenticated = *
          message       = Helo name contains a ip address (HELO was $sender_helo_name) and not is valid
          condition     = ${if match{$sender_helo_name}{\N((\d{1,3}[.-]\d{1,3}[.-]\d{1,3}[.-]\d{1,3})|([0-9a-f]{8})|([0-9A-F]{8}))\N}{yes}{no}}
          condition     = ${if match {${lookup dnsdb{>: defer_never,ptr=$sender_host_address}}\}{$sender_helo_name}{no}{yes}}
          delay         = 45s

  drop    !authenticated = *
          condition     = ${if isip{$sender_helo_name}}
          message       = Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.3)

  drop    !authenticated = *
          condition     = ${if eq{[$interface_address]}{$sender_helo_name}}
          message       = $interface_address is _my_ address

  accept


acl_check_rcpt:
  accept  hosts         = :

  deny message = Too many recipients, limit is $acl_c_max_recipients recipients
  set acl_c_max_recipients=${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/exim4/limit_per_email_account_max_recipients}{$value}{LIMIT_PER_EMAIL_ACCOUNT_MAX_RECIPIENTS}}
  condition = ${if >{$rcpt_count}{$acl_c_max_recipients}}

  deny message = Email account is sending too much emails [limitlog]: deny / email / $authenticated_id / $sender_rate / $sender_rate_period [limit=$acl_c_limit_per_hour]
  set acl_c_limit_per_hour=${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/exim4/limit_per_email_account_max_sent_emails_per_hour}{$value}{LIMIT_PER_EMAIL_ACCOUNT_MAX_SENT_EMAILS_PER_HOUR}}
  ratelimit = $acl_c_limit_per_hour / 1h / $authenticated_id

  warn ratelimit = 0 / 1h / strict / $authenticated_id
  set acl_c_limit_per_hour=${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/exim4/limit_per_email_account_max_sent_emails_per_hour}{$value}{LIMIT_PER_EMAIL_ACCOUNT_MAX_SENT_EMAILS_PER_HOUR}}
  log_message = Sender rate [limitlog]: log / email / $authenticated_id / $sender_rate / $sender_rate_period [limit=$acl_c_limit_per_hour]

  warn    set acl_m3    = no
  
  warn    !authenticated = *
          hosts          = !+relay_from_hosts
          condition     = ${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/aliases}{true}{false}}
          set acl_m3    = yes

  deny    message       = Restricted characters in address
          domains       = +local_domains
          local_parts   = ^[.] : ^.*[@%!/|]

  deny    message       = Restricted characters in address
          domains       = !+local_domains
          local_parts   = ^[./|] : ^.*[@%!] : ^.*/\\.\\./

  require verify        = sender

  accept  hosts         = +relay_from_hosts
          control       = submission

  accept  authenticated = *
          control       = submission/domain=

  deny    message       = Rejected because $sender_host_address is in a black list at $dnslist_domain\n$dnslist_text
          hosts         = !+whitelist
          dnslists      = ${readfile {/etc/exim4/dnsbl.conf}{:}}

  require message       = relay not permitted
          domains       = +local_domains : +relay_to_domains

  deny    message       = smtp auth requried
         sender_domains = +local_domains
         !authenticated = *

  require verify        = recipient

.ifdef CLAMD
  warn    set acl_m0    = no

  warn    condition     = ${if exists {/etc/exim4/domains/$domain/antivirus}{yes}{no}}
          set acl_m0    = yes
.endif

.ifdef SPAMASSASSIN
  warn    set acl_m1    = no

  warn    condition     = ${if exists {/etc/exim4/domains/$domain/antispam}{yes}{no}}
          set acl_m1    = yes
.endif

  accept


acl_check_data:

  deny senders = /etc/exim4/deny_senders

.ifdef CLAMD
  deny   message        = Message contains a virus ($malware_name) and has been rejected
         malware        = */defer_ok
         condition      = ${if eq{$acl_m0}{yes}{yes}{no}}
.endif

.ifdef SPAMASSASSIN
  warn   !authenticated = *
         hosts          = !+relay_from_hosts
         condition      = ${if < {$message_size}{600K}}
         condition      = ${if eq{$acl_m1}{yes}{yes}{no}}
         spam           = nobody:true/defer_ok
         add_header     = X-Spam-Score: $spam_score_int
         add_header     = X-Spam-Bar: $spam_bar
         add_header     = X-Spam-Report: $spam_report
         set acl_m2     = $spam_score_int

  warn   condition      = ${if !eq{$acl_m2}{} {yes}{no}}
         condition      = ${if >{$acl_m2}{SPAM_SCORE} {yes}{no}}
         add_header     = X-Spam-Status: Yes
         message        = SpamAssassin detected spam (from $sender_address to $recipients).
.endif

  accept


acl_check_mime:
  deny   message        = Blacklisted file extension detected
         condition      = ${if match {${lc:$mime_filename}}{\N(\.ade|\.adp|\.bat|\.chm|\.cmd|\.com|\.cpl|\.exe|\.hta|\.ins|\.isp|\.jse|\.lib|\.lnk|\.mde|\.msc|\.msp|\.mst|\.pif|\.scr|\.sct|\.shb|\.sys|\.vb|\.vbe|\.vbs|\.vxd|\.wsc|\.wsf|\.wsh|\.jar)$\N}{1}{0}}

  accept



######################################################################
#                   AUTHENTICATION CONFIGURATION                     #
######################################################################
begin authenticators

dovecot_plain:
  driver = dovecot
  public_name = PLAIN
  server_socket = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
  server_set_id = $auth1

dovecot_login:
  driver = dovecot
  public_name = LOGIN
  server_socket = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
  server_set_id = $auth1



######################################################################
#                      ROUTERS CONFIGURATION                         #
#               Specifies how addresses are handled                  #
######################################################################
begin routers

#smarthost:
#  driver = manualroute
#  domains = ! +local_domains
#  transport = remote_smtp
#  route_list = * smartrelay.vestacp.com
#  no_more
#  no_verify

dnslookup:
  driver = dnslookup
  domains = !+local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  no_more

localuser_spam:
  driver = accept
  transport = local_spam_delivery
  condition = ${if eq {${if match{$h_X-Spam-Status:}{\N^Yes\N}{yes}{no}}} {${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/passwd}{yes}{no_such_user}}}}

userforward:
  driver = redirect
  check_local_user
  file = $home/.forward
  require_files = ${local_part}:+${home}/.forward
  domains = +local_domains
  allow_filter
  no_verify
  no_expn
  check_ancestor
  file_transport = address_file
  pipe_transport = address_pipe
  reply_transport = address_reply

procmail:
  driver = accept
  check_local_user
  require_files = ${local_part}:+${home}/.procmailrc:/usr/bin/procmail
  transport = procmail
  no_verify

autoreplay:
  driver = accept
  require_files = /etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/autoreply.${local_part}.msg
  condition = ${if exists{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/autoreply.${local_part}.msg}{yes}{no}}
  retry_use_local_part
  transport = userautoreply
  unseen

aliases:
  driver = redirect
  headers_add = X-redirected: yes
  data = ${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/aliases}}}}
  require_files = /etc/exim4/domains/$domain/aliases
  redirect_router = dnslookup
  pipe_transport = address_pipe
  unseen

localuser_fwd_only:
  driver = accept
  transport = devnull
  condition = ${if exists{/etc/exim4/domains/$domain/fwd_only}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/fwd_only}{true}{false}}}}

localuser:
  driver = accept
  transport = local_delivery
  condition = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/passwd}{true}{false}}

catchall:
  driver = redirect
  headers_add = X-redirected: yes
  require_files = /etc/exim4/domains/$domain/aliases
  data = ${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{*@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/aliases}}}}
  file_transport = local_delivery
  redirect_router = dnslookup

terminate_alias:
  driver = accept
  transport = devnull
  condition = ${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/aliases}{true}{false}}



######################################################################
#                      TRANSPORTS CONFIGURATION                      #
######################################################################
begin transports

remote_smtp:
  driver = smtp
  #interface = ${if eq{$acl_m3}{yes}{FIRSTIP}{${lookup{$sender_address_domain}lsearch{/etc/exim4/virtual/interfaces} {$value}{SECONDIP}}}}
  #helo_data = "${if eq{$acl_m3}{yes}{FIRSTHOST}{${lookup{$sending_ip_address}lsearch{/etc/exim4/virtual/helo_data}{$value}{SECONDHOST}}}}"
  dkim_domain = DKIM_DOMAIN
  dkim_selector = mail
  dkim_private_key = DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY
  dkim_canon = relaxed
  dkim_strict = 0
  hosts_try_fastopen = 
  hosts_try_chunking = !93.188.3.0/24
  message_linelength_limit = 1G

procmail:
  driver = pipe
  command = "/usr/bin/procmail -d $local_part"
  return_path_add
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  user = $local_part
  initgroups
  return_output

local_delivery:
  driver = appendfile
  maildir_format
  maildir_use_size_file
  user = ${extract{2}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/passwd}}}}
  group = mail
  create_directory
  directory_mode = 770
  mode = 660
  use_lockfile = no
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add
  directory = "${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/passwd}}}}/mail/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/${lookup{$local_part}dsearch{${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/passwd}}}}/mail/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}}}"
  quota = ${extract{6}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/passwd}}}}M
  quota_warn_threshold = 75%

local_spam_delivery:
  driver = appendfile
  maildir_format
  maildir_use_size_file
  user = ${extract{2}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/passwd}}}}
  group = mail
  create_directory
  directory_mode = 770
  mode = 660
  use_lockfile = no
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add
  directory = "${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/passwd}}}}/mail/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/${lookup{$local_part}dsearch{${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/passwd}}}}/mail/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}}}/.Spam"
  quota = ${extract{6}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/passwd}}}}M
  quota_directory = "${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/passwd}}}}/mail/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/${lookup{$local_part}dsearch{${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/passwd}}}}/mail/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}}}"
  quota_warn_threshold = 75%

address_pipe:
  driver = pipe
  return_output

address_file:
  driver = appendfile
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add

address_reply:
  driver = autoreply

userautoreply:
  driver = autoreply
  file = /etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/autoreply.${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/accounts}}}}.msg
  from = "${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}/accounts}}}}@${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim4/domains/}}"
  headers = Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
  subject = "${if def:h_Subject: {Autoreply: \"${rfc2047:$h_Subject:}\"} {Autoreply Message}}"
  to = "${sender_address}"

devnull:
  driver = appendfile
  file = /dev/null



######################################################################
#                      RETRY CONFIGURATION                           #
######################################################################
begin retry

# Address or Domain    Error       Retries
# -----------------    -----       -------
*                      *           F,2h,15m; G,16h,1h,1.5; F,4d,6h



######################################################################
#                      REWRITE CONFIGURATION                         #
######################################################################
begin rewrite



######################################################################

On the left the telnet connection for IMAP, on the right the connection to SMTP
Telnet-Connection
The requests to the exim4 server first go to a pfsense, but this forwards the request to the server with NAT and the retrieval of mails also works.
If further data is needed, please write which and where I can find it.

Does your ISP block port 25 outgoing? You should include more information about your config, including relevant config files for exim.

My ISP does not block outgoing traffic to port 25

Can you use tcpdump and/or Wireshark to check when the connection breaks? Does TLS handshake complete, is mail data sent, does the connection fail on termination?
